# Highcharts stacked bar chart: adding categories and data to series

Tags: javascript

I have the following stacked bar chart: http://jsfiddle.net/bvuWR/1/
I have question, in which way I could add a category and I could add series data for that additional category?
I tried to find function for categories adding in Highstock documentation, but didn't find any suitable except addPoint.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/bvuWR/1/
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got to do 2 things to update the categories:

1: Append the next category to the list using the setCategories() method - In the example I add in the Lemon category to the original list. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I can only add a category but only set the whole list at once.

2: Update the each series object with a point for the value of the Lemon category using addPoint()

```
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Lemon']);

for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++)
{
   chart.series[i].addPoint(Math.random() * 5, true, true);
}
```

Check out this example on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bvuWR/106/

Here is the official highcharts reference for the above:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories()

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()

Answer (score 0):

That question appears to have been answered in a previous posting:

[Adding a series dynamically with HighCharts Stock Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675496/adding-a-series-dynamically-with-highcharts-stock-charts)

also: I demonstrate highcharts by adding/removing series data in a responsive design.
Review the chart.js javascript to view how it was put together.

http://www.informed-design.com/responsive/chart/