# Highchart dynamic data adding with addSeries array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, dynamic, highcharts

How can I manage this or making this dynamic? I am using a highchart bar, and I don't know how to make this part of the code to be a dynamic :

```
series: [{
         name: 'Clinic 1',
         data: [3, 3, 4, 7, 3]
     }, {
         name: 'Clinic 2',
         data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 4]
     }, {
         name: 'Clinic 3',
         data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 1]
     }]
```

here in my situation, i am trying to make it dynamic, i have no idea how to make the `data:[]` to be a dynamic, something like my problem is the length of the array `data[]` and also, another problem, i've also know a little bit about `addSeries` function, where its syntax is :

```
chart.addSeries({
    name: example
    data: example
})
```

can i separate the name and the data within it? because if i will include the name in populating the loop, it would duplicate, also i am thinking that i need a multiple loop for populating the `data` part of the `addseries` function
Here is my code where i have all the data, but i don't know how to plot it with `addSeries` to be a dynamic.

```
function getbarxAxis() {
  getallclinics();
  var arrayLength = myclinicsID.length;
 $.ajax({
   url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardata_date",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(data) {
     for (var i in myclinicsID) {
       categories.push(data[i]["datemonths"]);

          for(var innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < arrayLength; innerLoop++) {        
            getbarSeriesData(myclinicsID[innerLoop],data[i]['datemonths']);

         }
     }
    loadChart(categories);
   }
 });
}
    function getbarSeriesData(clinicID,month) {
    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl+"patients_report/get_checkup/"+month+"/"+clinicID,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          alert (data[0]['total_check']);
        }
    });
}
```

Here in my code, I already plotted the xAxis, where it consist of months: then every xAxis, I queried it to get the data, every months, and now I am struggling how to plot the data, where I need to separate the `addSeries` `name` and `data` because I will go with the first loop for the `name`, and the second loop, there I will put the `data` something like this:

```
for (var i in myclinicsID) {
chart.addSeries {
name: myclinicsNAME[i]
}

for(var innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < arrayLength; innerLoop++) {
  getbarSeriesData(myclinicsID[innerLoop],data[i]['datemonths']); // inside of this is the addseries data
}
}
```

CONSOLE FOR

```
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/March/1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 83ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/March/2 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 76ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/March/3 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 165ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/March/4 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 70ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/April/1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 87ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/April/2 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 142ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/April/3 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 180ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/clinic/patients_report/get_checkup/April/4 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 146ms]
```

each console has this response:

```
0:Object
  clinic_name: "Clinic 1"
  total_check: "0"
```

Comment: any answers pls?

Comment: can you update question with console log of data return for  function `getbarSeriesData(clinicID,month)` and array `categories.push(data[i]["datemonths"])`.

Comment: @Deep3015 hello thanks for your reply. very appreciated. i editted it sir. we can discuss for more results

Comment: @Deep3015 hello sir? how can i plot in that situation?.. something how can i use the chart.addSeries? please help me

Comment: i want  console log of return data of function `getbarSeriesData(clinicID,month)` and  categories inside function `getbarxAxis()` . What you have updated is confusing

Comment: @Deep3015 every result has an object function sir. 0:Object
  clinic_name: "Clinic 1"
  total_check: "0"

Comment: @Deep3015 can you please help me how to construct the data to plot? within my results?

Comment: Yes, you can separate `data` and `name`. First add series: `chart.addSeries({ name: 'something' });` then later you can use `chart.series[index_of_series].setData(data);`.

Comment: @PawełFus sir, very much appreciated reply. thank you.. can you help me in my situation ?

Comment: @PawełFus hello sir, i got all the data that i need , i only need is to plot, but its hard to do with my situation

Comment: Please, read carefully my comment above. You can use one loop for adding series, and another loop for setting data.

Comment: @PawełFus hello sir, my concern is, how do i make data[,,,,]  , i mean this is what my loop goes, first loop, i got data from the month march for each clinic, so i got 4 clinics then i got 4 values, then second loop another month, i got 4 clinics again thats why i got 4 values, then it must be , [1,1], [1,1], [1,1] ,[1,1], how can i make something like that ? and also do i need to make a two dimensional array for that?  for clinic 1:data[0][1,1] for clinic2: data[1][1,1], for clinic3: data[3][1,1] and so on.. ? please help me

Comment: Format for Highcharts data should be: `data: [ [x_1, y_1], [x_2, y_2], ... , [x_N, y_N] ]`. For example: `var data_clinic_1 = [];`. Then loop over your data and push that values: `data_clinic_1.push([ x_value, y_value ]);`. And last step would be `chart.series[1].setData(data_clinic_1);`.

Comment: @PawełFus what if i got another month? it will be [x1,x2,x3], then how can i make it dynamic? like the array size or ? hmm. i am confuse, becoz i am getting the data by using recursive way, i mean it's hard in my situation because i am making month: x axis(dynamic) and the series also to be dynamic, by querrying it in database as being data driven chart

Comment: When you receive another point (pair: `[x, y]`), then you can use [`chart.series[index].addPoint([x, y]);`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint).

Comment: @PawełFus sir, in my situation, i am getting data one by one, something like, first loop i got january so [1,x] [2,x] [1.x] [2,x] and second loop is [x,1],[x,2],[x,3],[x,1]. something like that .. can you help me plot in that situation ? thanks.. reply appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142741/discussion-between-jc-john-and-pawel-fus).

Comment: "Something like that" is not the best description.. Something like my answers above should work ;) How about this: don't use `setData()`, use `addPoint()` only. For example: `chart.series[index].addPoint(['April', total_check] );`.

Comment: @PawełFus can i do chart.series[index].addPoint([total_check] ); ? because i already filled my categories of datemonths? or maybe i could duplicate chart.series[index].addPoint(['April', total_check] );

Comment: @PawełFus here is my new updated question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647911/highchart-bar-plotting-data-doesnt-work-by-javascript

Comment: Yes, you can use `chart.series[index].addPoint([total_check] );`. Each next point will be rendered as a new category.